# Output in the desired format from the test.wilcoxon function

Tags: r, dataframe, pairwise.wilcox.test

My data.frame:

```
data <-structure(list(col1 = c(125L, 654L, 896L, 154L, 865L, 148L), 
    col2 = c(489L, 657L, 198L, 269L, 789L, 456L), col3 = c(741L, 
    852L, 963L, 987L, 951L, 632L), col4 = c(124L, 785L, 874L, 
    965L, 563L, 145L), col5 = c(963L, 146L, 259L, 367L, 365L, 
    189L), col6 = c(741L, 777L, 100L, 200L, 956L, 452L), col7 = c(456L, 
    666L, 300L, 778L, 888L, 999L), col8 = c(254L, 732L, 400L, 
    500L, 600L, 700L), col9 = c(555L, 638L, 127L, 489L, 545L, 
    54L), col10 = c(921L, 549L, 111L, 222L, 354L, 355L), GROUP = c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

My fun:

```
combination <- list(c(1,2),c(1,3),c(2,3),c(4,5),c(4,6),c(5,6),c(7,8),c(7,9),c(8,9))

wilcox.fun <- function(df, id_group){
  df = df[df$GROUP%in%id_group,]
  x <- function(dat) { 
    do.call(rbind, Map(function(x, y) {
      col1 <- dat[[x[1]]]
      col2 <- dat[[x[2]]]
        test <- wilcox.test(col1, col2,conf.int = TRUE)
        print("work")
        median.group.1 <- median((dat[[x[1]]]))
        median.group.2 <- median((dat[[x[2]]]))
        diff.1 <- -round(test$estimate, 2)
      data.frame(NAME = sprintf('Group %s by Group %s',x[1],x[2]),
       
        stats=paste(x[1],":",median.group.1,":",x[2],median.group.2),
        
        diff=paste(x[1],"-",x[2],diff.1,collapse = "\n")
                 
      
    

      )
    }, combination))
  }
  return (purrr::map_df(split(data, data$GROUP),x, .id ="GROUP"))
}
  
    
result <- wilcox.fun(data, c("1","2"))



names(result)[3] <- "stats"
names(result)[4] <- "diff"
```

I would like the function to output data in this format:

```
|GROU| 1    | 2  | 3   |  4  | 5   |  6  | 7 | 8 | 9   |       dif      |
     |------|----|-----|-----|-----|-----|---|---|-----|----------------|        |
|1   | 139.5| 379|864  |544.5|665  |470.5|617|377|522  | 1 - 2 239.5    |
|    |                                                 | 1 - 3 724.5    |    
|    |                                                 | 2 - 3 485      |
|    |                                                 | 4 - 5 120.5    |
|    |                                                 | etc            |
|--- |------|----|-----|-----|-----|-----|---|---|-----|----------------|
|2   |759.5 |723 |901.5|674  |255.5|866.5|777|666|591.5|1 - 2 -36.5     |   |
|    |                                                 |1 - 3 142       |   |
|    |                                                 |2 - 3 178.5     |   |
|    |                                                 |4 - 5 -418.5    |   |
|    |                                                 | etc            |   |
```

that is, I want a data frame to be formed in which medians are recorded in each new column without repetition, and all comparisons of medians are in one column.
I don't quite understand how to form such a data frame

Comment: This looks like a pointless exercise. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve with this, what is your goal? What is the research question you are trying to answer?

Comment: My function takes 2 columns, reads medians for them, writes from to the status column. It also takes for these two columns finds the median for retail and writes it to the diff column. For each group. I am not satisfied with this data output.frame.and I want to make it output in the format that I need (in the form of a table that is in the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

```
wilcox.fun <- function(data, id_groups, combination){
  
  result_list <- list()
  for (g in id_groups){
    
    df = as.matrix(data[data$GROUP %in% g,])
    df <- df[,unique(unlist(combination))]
    med <- apply(df, 2, median)
    
    result <- data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol=length(med)+2, nrow=1))
    result[1,] <- c(g, med, NA)
    
    for (k in 1:(length(combination))) {
      
      i <- combination[[k]][1]
      j <- combination[[k]][2]
      test <- wilcox.test(df[,i], df[,j],conf.int = TRUE)
      
      diff.1 <- -round(test$estimate, 2)
      result[k,length(med)+2] <- paste(i,"-", j, diff.1)
    }
    result_list[[g]] <- result
  }
  result_new <- do.call(rbind, result_list)
  names(result_new) <- c("GROUP", as.character(unique(unlist(combination))), "dif")

  return(result_new)
}

result <- wilcox.fun(data, c("1", "2"),combination)
result
   GROUP     1    2     3     4     5     6    7    8     9          dif
1.1     1 139.5  379   864 544.5   665 470.5  617  377   522  1 - 2 239.5
1.2  <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>  1 - 3 724.5
1.3  <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>    2 - 3 485
1.4  <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>  4 - 5 120.5
1.5  <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>    4 - 6 -74
1.6  <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA> 5 - 6 -194.5
1.7  <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>   7 - 8 -240
1.8  <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>    7 - 9 -95
1.9  <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>    8 - 9 145
2.1     2 759.5  723 901.5   674 255.5 866.5  777  666 591.5  1 - 2 -36.5
2.2  <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>    1 - 3 142
2.3  <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>  2 - 3 178.5
2.4  <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA> 4 - 5 -418.5
2.5  <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>  4 - 6 192.5
2.6  <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>    5 - 6 611
2.7  <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>   7 - 8 -111
2.8  <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA> 7 - 9 -185.5
2.9  <NA>  <NA> <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> <NA> <NA>  <NA>  8 - 9 -74.5
```

Comment: it looks like what I need, but I would like to find medians for each group and in one cell the difference of medians

Comment: you take the median for the entire column, and I would like only for each group

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you could just apply the function groupwise, e.g. `result_g1 <- wilcox.fun(data, c("1")), result_g2 <- wilcox.fun(data, c("2")), ...`.

Comment: Just when I enter `c("1","2")`. I get some strange result

Comment: So you want to be able to use the function with the statement c("1", "2") and get two tables: One per group, comparing within each group the medians of the columns? See my updated version of the solution. You can now also use the combination vector to define which combinations of columns you want to assess.

Comment: I would like to receive. updated it in the question

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the clarification. See my updated solution now.

Comment: not what I wanted, I expected it to be in one data frame, diff in one cell and only for selected columns

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240167/discussion-between-jkupzig-and-goga-goga).